# How can i show multi-value in a column using angular?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, servicenow

I am trying to create a HTML table with 3 columns ( Username - Email - City )
the city field is a reference on the table that called " City "
I need to show all the city that related to the user, so I have a user field for each city
and a basic table that contains the user & email.

the problem that I cannot pass multi cities(related for one user and email ) from the server to HTML and make the structure like this screenshot ( as a html table)

[image]

could anyone help? this is my angular js code

```
  data.users.push({
            userName:MY_USER_FROM_SERVER,
            email:"MY_EMAIL_FROM_SERVER",
            cities:[
                {name: "HERE I NEED TO GET THE CITY 1 from server!!!! "},
                {name: "HERE I NEED TO GET THE CITY 1 from server!!!!"},
                {name: "HERE I NEED TO GET THE CITY 1 from server!!!!"}
    
    NOTE: I HAVE N Cities! so how I can get all of them?
            ]
       });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<td><ng-container *ngFor="let city of user.cities;"><div>{{city.name}}</div></ng-container></td>
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bcode-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.